# Can I determine if a subscription is eligible for a "free tier" Cosmos DB account in an ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-rm-template

I'm writing an ARM template that will be executed as part of an installer for an app that will be distributed to some customers. The app depends on Cosmos DB. It would be preferable for the customer for the Cosmos DB account we create to be opted-in to the free tier.

As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/free-tier):

> You can have up to one free tier Azure Cosmos DB account per an Azure subscription

For most customers, the one we provision with our ARM template will be their first and only Cosmos DB account. In 90% of cases, therefore, we can probably enable the free tier with something like this:

```
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
        "apiVersion": "2020-03-01",
        // ...
        "properties": {
            "enableFreeTier": true,
```

However, some customers (perhaps larger customers, or those more adventurous with tech) will already have a Cosmos DB account and will likely have opted it in to the free tier.

Is there any way in an ARM template to determine whether the current subscription is still eligible for a free tier Cosmos DB account?

Comment: I don't think so. It's declarative language and not a script so you can't add any logic to it that can't be directly compiled. Even if you could the service principle you use for deployment may not have enough permissions to view other CosmosDB's (e.g. when they reside in a different resource group).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parameterize the `enableFreeTier` property and specify it at deployment time. Default it to true if you like. How that parameter is ascertained will depend on your deployment process.

Determining the value within the template won't be possible as @NotFound said.

Comment: This is my current approach - I'm allowing the customer to specify. I think I can use the .NET SDK to tell me if there are existing Cosmos accounts and if they are opted-in, but this again relies on the permissions being good enough to see the other account. Maybe I'll resort to a dirty try catch...